# MS-Access many to many relationship with subform having multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-access

In my database design there are 5 tables and i want my database to be able to save the course fee given by student. according to the design one student can enroll in many courses.

i want to accomplish this task using form can someone help me how to accomplish this task i am able to create form to save student with multiple course but i dont have idea how to design ms-access form from where i can save course fee given by student which can involved in multiple course.

here is link to my database design diagram:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIgqugOah3-SXdOSjByUnNiUnM/edit?usp=sharing

and here is form design to enter student with multiple course

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIgqugOah3-ZWdxd2tTZ1UzZTA/edit?usp=sharing

now i want a form which can add course fee given by student which is involved in multiple course.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that retains transactions. You'll want to create a semester ID or something similar to track the time period within which the course is taking place, bring in the course ID, and the student ID, pull from a table that lists each course and its fees, then in the form you'll list each of these details (probably have it default to the current semester to avoid needless data entry), and for reports or payment records, pull from this transaction table the course records by Student ID and Semester ID, and then create a record for payment amount and details (confirmation number or other such record that would correspond to record in the payment system).

You'll want to actually pull the costs from the price table into this transaction table rather than simply referencing them so that if the course prices change in the future, students records will not get updated for previous semesters they'd taken the courses in.